# Merge two data frames with different column names and exclude the equivalent key from the result

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two pandas data frames that share the same key, but its name is different in each object.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3], "Flag":[0,0,1]})
results = pd.DataFrame({"client_id":[1,2,3], "score":[600,700,800]})
df.columns
Index(['ID', 'Flag'])
results.columns
Index(['client_id', 'score'])
```

I want to merge them together to add `results["score"]` to `df`. I tried the following:

```py
df = pandas.merge(df, results, left_on="ID", right_on="client_id", how="left")
```

This works well, but `df` now has four columns: `["ID","Flag","client_id","score"]`.

I am just sightly confused. Why is `merge` returning the second data frame's key even though I told it `df["ID"]` and `results["client_id"]` are the key to merge by?

The expected result would be:

```py
df.columns
Index(['ID', 'Flag', 'score'])
```

Other `merge` functions that I have used don't do this, so I'm simply wondering why `pandas` does. Is there a specific reason to this (i.e. can keeping the second data frame's key ever be useful?)?

The main question is: is there an argument in `merge` that I can use to avoid this or would I have to exclude `df["client_id"]` manually?

Comment: I'm invoking `x/y problem`: please explain why you're insistent that `merge` perform the entire operation for you.  With the restrictions you appear to set, you're simply grumbling that `merge` wasn't written the way you want.  If this is the case, you've posted to the wrong site.

Comment: The other merge functions that I've used don't do this (for example, the `merge` function in `R` ). So I'm looking for a solution to avoid writing things that I wouldn't have to write in another language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is `merge` returning the second data frame's key even though I
>   told it `df["ID"]` and `results["client_id"]` are equivalent?

You didn't tell they are equivalent. You told pandas to match these data frames by *those* keys. It could be the case that you had 1 million entries in  `df['ID']`, 1 million entries in `df['client_id']`, but only 10 entries actually matched. So, what to do in this case? Are these columns *equivalent*?

Depending on `how` you merge, the behavior differs. If you perform an `outer` merge, for instance, you'd get a merged dataframe with *very very different* `df['ID']` and `df['client_id']` columns.

As an exercise, consider this example:

```
results = pd.DataFrame({"client_id":[1,2,3,4], "score":[600,700,800,900]})
```

Now, `client_id` has a 4th row. In merging `how='outer'`, you get

```
    ID  Flag  client_id  score
0  1.0   0.0          1    600
1  2.0   0.0          2    700
2  3.0   1.0          3    800
3  NaN   NaN          4    900
```

without the `client_id` column, it gets harder to explain why there's a 4th row after the merger.

---

If you really want to make these columns *"equivalent"* (i.e. drop them at merge and keep the dominant column), rename them to have the same name and use `on` for one unique key, instead of `left_on` and `right_on` keys.

```
pd.merge(df, results.rename(columns={'client_id':'ID'}), on='ID', how='left')

   ID  Flag  score
0   1   0.0    600
1   2   0.0    700
2   3   1.0    800
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to get what you want is to change one column name before the merge.

`merge` retains both columns to cover the case of an ID that exists in only one of the two data frames being merged.  See standard data base operations for the semantics.

Briefly, consider this case, with mismatched IDs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3], "Flag":[0,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"client_id":[1,2,4], "score":[600,700,800]})
```

The columns are *not* equivalent; the merged df will appropriately preserve the source information for whatever purposes you had.  Had you wanted *equivalent* columns, you would have given them the same name and made sure all the entries matched.  Any deviation from that definition of *equivalent* means that you, the supreme source of all correct information, have something else in mind.